# C# - check if List<> is initialized

Tags: c#, list, initialization, out

I have function that accept `out List<int> list` as parameter. How can I check if `list` is initialized or not?

This code gives me the `Use of unassigned out parameter 'list'` error:

```
public void CheckList(out List<int> list)
    {
        if (list == null) {
            list = List<int>();
        }
    //Rest of the code
    }
```

Facts that I have checked:

> - Variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed in a method call. However, the called method is
>     required to assign a value before the method returns. [out parameter
>     modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

Edit:
I want my method to be able to accept both options: list with elemtns and append aditional elements to it or in other case to initialize list and add elements to it.

Comment: So you have the answer in your quote... you might wanted to use `ref` instead.

Comment: I don't. I want to leave this decision to the caller. If input is uninitialized, then this method will initialize the List and add variables to it, otherwise, it would just append new variables to already existing list.

Comment: You cant. And null doesnt mean not initialized. It is initialized to null. If you'd like to check for null then use ref - it will force the user of the function to pass an initialized variable. Then you can check if it is initialized to null or not and if so to initialize to an empty list.

Comment: Also there is no meaning to pass an initialized variable to an out parameter. You cant use it inside the function as you just witnessed

Comment: I would initialize it inside a function. It would then be initialized when function exits. Looks like only option is to force caller to input an initialized array and use `ref`.

Comment: Again, with ref the caller can pass a variable initialized to null. Anyhow, another option for you is to return the list, and let the user decide what to do with it. I.e add to an existing list or use just the returned list

Comment: `out` means it’s a pure output parameter, and therefore there is no input which means the parameter is uninitialized by definition. You obviously can’t get input semantics with `out` and if you want it you need to use `ref` as proposed by others.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with **out** argument then most certainly it isn't initialized because the method should initialize it.
If it was passed by "ref", then you would check it.

Comment: What if I have a case when state of `list` is not known in advance, or method would like to accept both options? Since you cannot define overloaded methods that differ only on `ref` and `out`.

Comment: It is either ref or out. With former you can pass an instance while the other can only return an instance. Perhaps if you are returning only, you might consider using return argument instead.

Comment: I want to use out, to pass an instance. At the same time I want the method to be able to accept initialized ur uninitialized list.

Comment: Then use *ref* instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a wrapper?

```
public void CheckListWrapper(ref List<int> list)
{
    if(list == null)
    { 
        CheckList(out list);
    }
    else
    {
        //append whatever
    }
}

public void CheckList(out List<int> list)
{
     list = List<int>();       
    //Rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a new parameter for `sameList` and it will work for you so 
what about this one. There is no more way to accept without Initialization.

```
private static void Main()
    {
        List<int> i=null;
        CheckList(out i,i);
        Console.WriteLine(i[0]);
    }
    public static void CheckList(out List<int> list,List<int> sameList)
    {
        list = sameList;
        if(list==null)
        {
            //Intialize
            list = new List<int>();
            list.Add(1);
        }
        else
        {
            //append
            list.Add(12);
        }
        //Rest of the code
    }
```

Comment: `List<int> i=null;` in this case i is initialized variable. It is initialized to `null`. I am looking for some sort of method, that can check status of the variable (initialized/uninitialized)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
bool IsInitialised(List myList) {
    if ( (myList!= null) && (!myList.Any()) )
     {
         return true;
     }
return false;
}
```

A linq-less way will be:

```
if(myList != null && myList.Count == 0){
  // The list is empty. Add something here
}
```

From your calling method like Main:
Pseudo code. Testmethod(ref list) and TestMethod(list) have different signature so they both compile.

```
if(IsInitialised(list))
 Call TestMethod(ref list);
Else call TestMethod(list);
```

Comment: It gives me `Use of unassigned out parameter 'myList'`

Comment: Edited the code. Please see. If downvoted, would be great to get positive feedback

Comment: That would work, but you need two methods for that. Intention of the question was, if there is an option to determine the state of the `list` parameter (initialized/uninitialized).
I didn't downvote on your answer.

Comment: There s no method overloading for ref and out. They both have same signature at IL level. You can look at same method name with list and ref list as parameter

Comment: I have edited the answer. This is the closest you can get